# change the popup message in a required field

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I have a select dojo controller.

```
<select dojoType="dijit.form.Select" data-dojo-attach-point="drpSomthing" id="drpSomthing"
                data-dojo-props="regExp:'\\d{5}', required:true, invalidMessage:'Invalid zip code.'"></select>
```

this is a required field. I want to change the popup message from "This value is required" to something else. I tried to use the `"invalidMessage"`, `"promptMessage"` and the `"Missing message"` but it didn't help.
Hoe do I change the popup message?

regards

Kobi

Answer (score 1):

`dijit.form.Select` is getting the message from the `nls`: `i18n.getLocalization("dijit.form", "validate", this.lang).missingMessage`
and not from a local property.

This happens in the `postMixInProperties` method of `dijit.form.Select` (see https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/form/Select.js#L364)

You can do two things:

- after your `dijit.form.Select` is created, update its property `_missingMsg`

like this:

```
mySelect._missingMsg = 'what ever message you want';
```

(but this is dirty as you are changing a private property)

- or, cleaner way : you create a new widget, extending `dijit.form.Select` where you redefine the `postMixInProperties` and you use this new widget in place of `dijit.form.Select`

like this:

```js
define([
 "dojo/_base/declare",
 "dijit/form/Select"
], function(declare, Select) {
     return declare([Select], {
       postMixInProperties: function(){
   // summary:
   //  set the missing message
   this.inherited(arguments);
   this._missingMsg = 'What ever message you want';
  }
     });
});
```